# log4j: Write to a log file with a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, log4j

I am trying to use log4j to print logs to a log file. It works perfectly. But when I export the project as a jar file and run it I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.mkyong.HelloExample.<clinit>(HelloExample.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

The project structure is as follows https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Of corse. Your problem is that you need to include the `log4j.jar` library when executing. You may do it in either of two ways:

- Manually: If you run the jar within Eclipse, it is enough to execute Run As > Run Configurations... > classpath > Add JARS (or external JARs) and select the `log4j.jar`.
- Automatically: Include into the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file a classpath declaration:

  `Class-Path: log4j.jar`

(See the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)).

This way has the advantage that you won't have to include libraries at execution time, even when executing out of Eclipse. But remember to distribute the `log4.jar` along with your own jar.